# Outlook 365: Play notification sound only once every X minutes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications, email-filter

Currently I have my settings to display a notification and play a sound whenever I receive a new email. However, I often, like many others, receive multiple emails at the same time or within a few minutes of each other.

With the current settings, this leads to a notification sound one after the other every couple of minutes. *I would like a way to specify that the sound should only occur if a sound notification hasn't occurred in the past X minutes*.

After searching, I found that I can turn of the default notification setting and then create a rule that only certain emails should generate a sound notification; however, this solution doesn't work for groups that are sending important emails in quick succession.

This seems like it would be a common need, so I feel like I have missed a simple solution somewhere. I truly have searched for a solution, but there is a chance my search skills are lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such option to specify that the sound should only occur if a sound notification hasn't occurred in the past X minutes.

It is encouraged to share your feedback via the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm unsure if I should mark this question as answered.